# How to rename links with question mark?

Tags: html, hyperlink, rename

I used to rename links with a question mark after them, like this:

`LinkName.mp4?` to `Anything I want.mp4`

So the link will be downloaded with "Anything I want" name, instead of "LinkName"...

But now, the question mark won't work anymore!

Is there any other way that I can rename links without any script?

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you can do this with simple changes in HTML. You can either rename the actual file (thus the link itself), or make a php script to implement this particular feature.

And one thing I dont understand, is that why dont you just change the displayed text of the link like

```
<a href="anything_you_want.mp4">LinkName</a>
```

---

Updated:

You can do it in html5 like this (doesnt work in old browsers):

```
<a href="linkname.mp4" download="anything_you_want.mp4">Link Title</a>
```

[MDN reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a)

Comment: Not the displayed text... If you click on you link here, It will be downloaded with this name: "anything_you_want.mp4"... But I want it to be downloaded with any name I want! I'm sure I did this with question mark before! But it won't work anymore...

Comment: Your old way is nonstandard. I've updated the answer, hope it helps.